# Disable Jenkins job with spaces in the name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Is there a way to disable a Jenkins job via the CLI that has spaces in the name? For example: -

```
ssh -l USERNAME -p 8081 SERVERNAME disable-job "Test Job"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try this: **ssh -l USERNAME -p 8081 SERVERNAME disable-job "Test%20Job"**

Comment: Doesn't work with the CLI

    ERROR: No such job �Test%20Job� exists. Perhaps you meant �Test Job�?
 
But I found a work around with curl

Comment: Are you sure � is not the result of pasted smart-quotes and not regular ( " ) quotes ? Maybe try single quote ( ’ ) ?

Comment: Tried with single quotes, got exactly the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work around to this. The CLI won't work with spaces in the job name, nothing I tried worked but this does: -

```
curl -X POST -L --user USERNAME:APITOKEN 'https://SERVERNAME/job/Test%20Job/disable'
```

You need to create an api token for your login in Jenkins first but disable/enable works with curl